# Qt- Set style sheet for multiple labels

Tags: qt

I have around 20 labels in my window. I want to set the same style sheet for 10 of them while setting another style for the others. Is there a better way to do this without setting style sheet for each label individually?

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    // Some code
    this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(65, 193, 244)");

    ui->label_id->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(60, 60, 60); "
                                     "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); "
                                     "border: 1px solid rgb(60, 60, 60);"
                                     "border-radius: 10px");
    ui->label_nickname->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(60, 60, 60); "
                                     "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); "
                                     "border: 1px solid rgb(60, 60, 60);"
                                     "border-radius: 10px");
    ui->label_name->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255); "
                                     "background-color: rgb(1, 153, 26); "
                                     "border: 1px solid rgb(26, 237, 61); "
                                     "border-radius: 10px");
    ui->label_age->setStyleSheet("color: rgb(255, 255, 255); "
                                     "background-color: rgb(1, 153, 26); "
                                     "border: 1px solid rgb(26, 237, 61); "
                                     "border-radius: 10px");
    // Some code
}
```

**UPDATE**:based on *Phạm Anh Tuấn* answer:

```
this->setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); color: rgb(65, 193, 244);"
                        "QLabel[type=1]"
                        "{"
                        "color: rgb(60, 60, 60);"
                        "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);"
                        "border: 1px solid rgb(60, 60, 60);"
                        "border-radius: 10px;"
                        "}"
                        );
ui->label_mstatus_yaw->setProperty("type", 1);
ui->label_mstatus_yaw->style()->unpolish(ui->label_mstatus_yaw);
ui->label_mstatus_yaw->style()->polish(ui->label_mstatus_yaw);
```

Comment: At least, you can create a `QString` with the qss definition to avoid code duplication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Dynamic properties and stylesheet. Refer: https://wiki.qt.io/Dynamic_Properties_and_Stylesheets

You can set stylesheet for whole ui:

```
QLabel[type="1"]
{
    color: rgb(60, 60, 60);
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid rgb(60, 60, 60);
    border-radius: 10px;
}

QLabel[type="2"]
{
    color: rgb(60, 60, 60);
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border: 1px solid rgb(60, 60, 60);
    border-radius: 10px"
}
```

Then change "type" property for label

```
ui->label_id->setProperty("type", 1);
this->style()->unpolish(ui->label_id);
this->style()->polish(ui->label_id);

ui->label_nickname->setProperty("type", 2);
this->style()->unpolish(ui->label_nickname);
this->style()->polish(ui->label_nickname);
```

Remember to do unpolish and polish after, the stylesheet will be applied for each "type" of QLabel
Sample code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw2t2i4cHmo_SmdMeGdfZ0VLb3M/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this is what I'm looking for. I'm just not sure where should I define `QLabel[type=x]`?

Comment: If all QLabels are children of "this" widget, you can append QLabel stylesheet to "this" stylesheet,
Example: this->setStyleSheet("QLabel[type=1]{...");

Comment: I've tried this but it had no effect on the target label. I've updated my question with the new code. What is wrong?

Comment: Sorry, stylesheet need change to QLabel[type="1"], QLabel[type="2"].
I updated my answer. And you can set style in .ui file
I attached my sameple code in my answer

Comment: And because stylesheet in "this" widget, so you have to call unpolish and polish with "this" 
Example: 
this->style()->unpolish(ui->label_id);
this->style()->polish(ui->label_id);

Comment: Thank you. It's working now. I set the styles in the .ui and it worked.

Comment: When you set stylesheet using this->setStyleSheet, you overrided stylesheet in .ui file. That's why it didnt work anymore. I suggest to set all stylesheet in .ui file. One more thing, your stylesheet "background-color: ..." has no scope. That means it will also affect to all children.

Comment: Glad to hear that

Comment: if you set property named "class", then you can write QLabel.TypeName in stylesheets instead of QLabel[type="TypeName"]

Answer (score 2):

Other approaches aside, you can easily iterate a fixed list of widgets. They're just pointers, and you have full power of C++ at your disposal.

```
const char stylesheet[] = "color: rgb(60, 60, 60); "
                   "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0); "
                   "border: 1px solid rgb(60, 60, 60);"
                   "border-radius: 10px";

// C++11

for (auto w : {ui->label_id, ui->label_nickname, ui->label_name, ui->label_age})
  w->setStyleSheet(stylesheet);

// C++98

QWidget * const widgets[] = {ui->label_id, ui->label_nickname, ui->label_name, ui->label_age};
int const count = sizeof(widgets)/sizeof(widgets[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) 
  widgets[i]->setStyleSheet(stylesheet);
```

Answer (score 1):

Write a class `StyledLabel` that derives from `QLabel` and sets its own style during initialization.

You can then use the *Promote Widget* functionality in Qt Creator/Designer to have the labels in the UI be of type `StyledLabel`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I think using this approach, I will not be able to change label's style in runtime, right?

Comment: You can always implement convenience methods in your custom widget that allow to trigger style settings. It could also be a slot that you wire to a signal, so you have a single signal make all custom widgets change their style. The options are endless.

Comment: Thanks @ypnos for your answer.